# запрос на Джанге переписать в оригинале

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Есть модель на джанге

```
class Category(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
     
 class Product(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

и чтобы получит все товары которые относятся определенному категорию я делаю вот такой запрос

```
Product.objects.filter(category_title='ilim')
```

а как написать такой же запрос на sqlite? прошу помочь

Comment: Что-то вроде такого: `SELECT * FROM Product, Category WHERE Product.category_id = Category.id and Category.title = 'ilim'`, хотя лучше через JOIN сделать. Кст, а если вывести `print(Product.objects.filter(category_title='ilim').query)`, то запрос будет отображен?

Comment: до, будет отображен

Comment: @django_starter, экстрасенсы в отпуске, прикладывайте текст ошибки :) И пишите при каком варианте ошибка, все-таки я 2 варианта писал

Comment: @gil9red получилось !! спс

Comment: @gil9red проблема была в том, что джанго добавляет префикс проекта, не product а main_product оказывается, без вашей помощи не получилось бы

Comment: @django_starter, пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ с решением :) А `print(Product.objects.filter(category_title='ilim').query)` этот вариант работает? Запрос выводится?

Comment: @gil9red dвы свой ответ напишите на этот вопрос, я вам галочку поставлю, а по поводу принт, не работает я внутри cli sqlite3 работал, ваш первый ответ помог

Comment: @gil9red а через join? еще проще пишится?

Comment: @django_starter, сами посмотрите на то как выглядит вариант с join :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Product, Category 
WHERE Product.category_id = Category.id and Category.title = 'ilim'
```

А с учетом добавления префиксов к названиям таблиц, то (тут для удобства добавил alias таблицам):

```
SELECT * FROM main_Product p, main_Category c 
WHERE p.category_id = c.id and c.title = 'ilim'
```

Если с `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM main_Product p 
LEFT JOIN 
    main_Category c ON p.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.title = 'ilim'
```

Comment: без join попроще)